# Resizing views that were designed with constraints

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder, constraints

I have an `NSView` xib, which contains a `NSTextField` and a custom `NSView`. I've used constraints so that when the parent view resizes, so do the children. So far so good. During a command, the user can show a third child object, which means I need to shuffle the other two views down, to fit it in. This works fine during my animation (I'm using `NSAnimationContext`), but the minute the view is resized, the children all snap back to their locations based on the constraints, ignoring the fact that I've altered the `frame.origin.y` or `frame.size.height` values.

How can I design a user interface which allows the use of constraints, but at the same time, allows me to tweak the relative positions of the UI elements programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following silvansky's answer, I solved the problem with the following:

```
const NSInteger offset = _textField.frame.size.height + 8;
NSRect newGridFrame = _grid.frame;
newGridFrame.size.height += show ? -offset : offset;

[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[NSAnimationContext currentContext].completionHandler = ^(void)
{
    _gridTopSpaceConstraint.constant += show ? offset : -offset;
    _textField.hidden = !show;
    _showingAddCategoryTextField = show;
};
[_grid.animator setFrame:newGridFrame];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

I couldn't get the `[NSLayoutConstraint constant]` property to animate directly, so had to do it by animating the frame, then changing the constraint once the animation had finished.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using constraints for the child views, then you are saying that you are delegating the position and size of those views to the runtime. You would expect things to break if you try to change those values programatically.

So what you need to do is change the constraints, rather than change those values.

When you've changed the constraints to match the new view you've added, then to animate to the new positions, do this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{[containingView layoutIfNeeded];}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make IBOutlets for certain constraints. So, you can adjust their constants (the only thing you can change in constraint) or relayout your view by removing old and adding new constraints.